# How to use map lambda of python to make a element to a certain number?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, lambda

I have a numpy.array called p2De. The first row has multiple elements may larger than 1. I want to set the elements which smaller than 1 to 1. Following is my code, but shows error... why? How to fix it?

```
bounde=1
p2De[:0]=map(lambda x:bounde if (x < bounde),p2Di[:0])

  File "C:\Users\wange\workspace\cathode\src\diffusion.py", line 86
    p2De[:0]=map(lambda x:bounde if (x < bounde),p2Di[:0])
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `p2Di[p2Di[:1] < bounde] = 1`

Comment: In addition to the solutions suggested, it looks like you need to replace `p2De[:0]` with `p2De[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an `else` for your `lambda` function :

```
lambda x:bounde if (x < bounde) else #stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
lambda x:bounde if (x < bounde) else x
```

You can also use list comprehension, which is more readable. Also, I would use the `max` builtin function instead of your lambda:

```
p2De[:0] = [max(x, bounde) for x in p2Di[:0]]
```

Comment: You want `min` here, not `max`.

Comment: No, you want `max`. The OP wrote "I want to set the elements which smaller than 1 to 1", that means he wants max(x, 1).

Comment: oops, it's my answer that needs correcting. I was so focused on other aspects of the problem that I misread his specs.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the syntax problem is in the `lambda`.

I don't think you want `p2De[:0]` - that's an empty array.  `p2De[0]` is the 1st row.  `p2De[0,:]` is the same, and makes it clear to the human readers that you have selected the 1st row of a 2d array.

The use of a map or comprehension works, but they don't offer much of an advantage, if any, over a simple loop (since you don't need to replace all of the values):

```
for i,v in enumerate(p2De[0,:]):
    if v<1:
        p2De[0,i] = 1
```

But none of these iterations is good `numpy` practice.  You should try to think in terms of vector operations.  A common practice is to use a boolean mask (or indexing) to select the values that should be changed:

```
I = p2De[0,:]<1  # boolean vector
p2De[0, I] = 1
p2De[0,p2De[0,:]<1]=1  # or one line form
```

There is also a `numpy` function that applies limits like this, `np.maximum`:

```
p2De[0,:] = np.maximum(p2De[0,:], 1)
```

`np.clip` applies both minimum and maximum bounds:

```
p2De[0,:] = np.clip(p2De[0,:], minbd, maxbd)
np.clip(p2De[0,:], minbd, maxbd, p2De[0,:])  # alt calling method
```

---

The Python(3) bosses encourage us to use functions and comprehensions over maps and lambdas.  For example if `plist` was a list like your `p2De[0,:]` row:

```
def clip(x):
    return 1 if x<1 else x 
plist = [clip(x) for x in plist]
plist = [min(x, 1) for x in plist] # using a builtin for this simple case
```

Comment: Thank you ! The clip is really help. Accurately, I have multiple boundary conditions. Clip simplified the code.

Answer (score 0):

say if you have a list a, you can do something like this:

```
    a=[2,3,1,7,0,0,8]
    bounde=1
    b = map(lambda n: n if n > bounde else bounde,a)
    print b
```